# Chrome bypassing server when making static requests to localhost

Tags: express, google-chrome-devtools

I have a node express app with middleware that's intercepting all calls before it serves static content:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request: ${req.url}`)
    next()
})

app.use('/', express.static('public'))
```

The `public` directory serves up a static website.

I get the initial document request logged when loading the site for the first time, but when I click a link on the site the static HTML content IS loaded, BUT

- the chrome dev tools don't show any network request
- the express middleware doesn't log any request

I'm trying to debug this middleware (there's additional logic to add), but Chrome isn't even making the request to the localhost express server and seemingly just loads the content direct from disk.

How can I get Chrome to send all `localhost` requests to the express server?

Comment: Are the files in `public` a SPA (like a React or Angular app) that wouldn't result in new requests? Or are the links hardcoded to disk and not to the relative URL (starting with `/`)?

Comment: The files in public are static HTML, the links are like `<a href="/docs/guide/intro/">` and resolve to `/public/docs/guide/intro/index.html` on disk

Comment: @ZacAnger I've figured out this is a static site with HTML but requests are being handled by a SPA (React), which is the reason behind this behaviour thanks.

Comment: An SPA means the page is not static.

Comment: Yes, the site is actually a Docusaurus one, I see the static content output from the `build` command, but only realised now that Docusaurus actually packs it and runs the site as a React app and doesn't request the static HTML at runtime.